# What is wrong or incorrect in the below JPQL query?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

Below is the JPQL query I wrote but it is not working. I get the following error: NoViableAltException: unexpected token: max

Can someone please point out the error in the below query?

```
SELECT new com.chp.cef.api.dto.EventSearchDTO(ec.eventName, e.eventKey, e.eventTime, CAST(e.messagePayload AS string), epl.status, epl.statusReason, CAST(epl.processLogPayload AS string), ec.source, " +
            "epl.eventProcessLogKey, epl.eventReceivedTime, epl.eventProcessedTime) FROM Event e " +
            "left join (SELECT inEpl.eventKey, max(inEpl.eventReceivedTime), inEpl.eventProcessLogKey, inEpl.status, inEpl.statusReason, inEpl.processLogPayload, inEpl.eventProcessedTime" +
            "FROM EventProcessLog inEpl GROUP BY inEpl.eventKey) epl ON e.eventKey = epl.eventKey " +
            "left join EventConfiguration ec ON e.eventConfigKey = ec.eventConfigurationKey WHERE ec.eventName = coalesce(:eventName, ec.eventName) " +
            "AND epl.status = coalesce(:eventStatus, epl.status) AND e.eventTime >= :eventStartTime AND e.eventTime <= :eventEndTime
```

Comment: The line 3 doesn't end with a space (`, inEpl.eventProcessedTime" +`) and line 4 doesn't start with a space (`FROM EventProcessLog`), therefore your JPL query contains the string `", inEpl.eventProcessedTimeFROM EventProcessLog "`, which is not a valid JPL query

Answer (score 0):

You can't join a subquery in JPQL/HQL. You will have to reformulate this to a correlated subquery in the ON clause.

Having said that, I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) along with the it's support for fetching the TOP-N per category through the `@Limit` annotation.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

But Blaze-Persistence not only helps you with the DTO mapping, it also enabled the use of some of the more advanced SQL concepts, in this case, lateral joins.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Event.class)
public interface EventSearchDTO {
    @IdMapping
    String getEventKey();
    String getEventName();
    Instant getEventTime();
    @Mapping("CAST_STRING(messagePayload)")
    String getMessagePayload();
    // ...

    @Limit(limit = "1", order = "eventReceivedTime DESC")
    @Mapping("EventProcessLog[eventKey = VIEW(eventKey)]")
    // If you have an association mapping, can be simplified to
    // @Mapping("processLogs")
    EventProcessLogDto getLatestLog();

    @EntityView(EventProcessLog.class)
    interface EventProcessLogDto {
        @IdMapping
        String getEventKey();
        String getEventProcessLogKey();
        // ...
    }

    @Mapping("EventConfiguration[eventConfigurationKey = VIEW(eventConfigKey)]")
    EventConfigurationDto getConfiguration();

    @EntityView(EventConfiguration.class)
    interface EventConfigurationDto {
        @IdMapping
        String getEventConfigurationKey();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`EventSearchDTO a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, EventSearchDTO.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

This will produce a SQL query similar to the following

```
SELECT ec.eventName, ... 
FROM Event e
left join lateral (SELECT * FROM EventProcessLog inEpl WHERE e.eventKey = inEpl.eventKey ORDER BY inEpl.eventReceivedTime DESC LIMIT 1) epl ON 1=1
left join EventConfiguration ec ON e.eventConfigKey = ec.eventConfigurationKey
```